# How to access updated redux store state in getServerSideProps next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to get the latest redux state in getServerSideProps like this :

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const state = store.getState();
    console.log(state.name);

    return { props: { login: false } };
};
```

But the result I get is the initial name state .

How can I get the latest persisted redux state in getServerSideProps next js ?

Comment: Why would you not expect it to return the initial state? You didn't dispatch any actions that would change it.

Comment: @HMR How can I get the latest persisted state ?? Please help

Comment: State isn't persisted on the server in the [redux next example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux). You could fetch data on the server and use (reverse) proxy to cache results but that doesn't work for user specific results when you have a lot of users or content that is very dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured I could only access the latest redux states by only using the latest redux config for next js which is available here :

[Next js redux example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux)